# How to Serve Private Images using NodeJs (and ExpressJs?) REST

Tags: node.js, image, rest, express, download

I have searched far and wide, but everyone seems to be focused on how to upload images to a NodeJs REST API. I'm already using Multer for that. Now I need to figure out how to download the private images through my REST API. When I say "private" I obviously mean that the images are specific to each user who is logged in - they are NOT publicly accessible nor are they accessible to anyone who is logged in except for the user who uploaded them. I tried ExpressJs's sendFile(), but it sends a binary file that is seemingly impossible for the client to transform and insert into an img element because it's not a blob. But what I'm REALLY asking is: Is there a mechanism/library already available to handle this, like Multer - except for DOWNLOADING PRIVATE images and letting me insert them into img elements?

Thanks for your suggestions. I'm using Vue and Vuetify on the front end, by the way.

Comment: "I tried ExpressJs's sendFile(), but it sends a binary file that is seemingly impossible for the client to transform and insert into an img element because it's not a blob." - that's odd because that's exactly what it's for. Please explain what differences you see in the HTTP response compared to serving it as a static file.

Comment: `but it sends a binary file that is seemingly impossible for the client to transform and insert into an img element` - try setting a correct `Content-Type` header, like `image/jpeg` or some such.

Comment: That's just it: I'm NEW. I don't know what the preferred method is. What IS the best method for serving PRIVATE images where the user is authenticated and given permission to "see" an [image] file and then the REST API method performs the download?

Comment: I understand what you mean by "that's exactly what it's for", but - HOW? The examples I've found don't use ExpressJs's sendFile() or they give an example for a different file type. My type is JPEG. What's the magic sequence of JavaScript function calls to get the response into an img element?

Comment: My final API call is... return res.sendFile(fileSpec); Am I missing some kind of options? The documentation states that the MIME type is automatically detected based on the extension. And it is in fact being downloaded.

Comment: On the front end, I'm... const data = res.data;
            var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(data);
            const blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView], { type: "image/jpeg" });
            var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            return urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob); // which is binded to the img's src // but this doesn't work - of course I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I looked at the response in detail, and the status is OK and the headers are fine and the data is there. The problem has to lie on the front end with the way I'm manipulating the response data, but I don't see anything wrong. The image shows as a broken image in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Discovered I was getting a blob size of 0 (via alert(blob.size)) due to Uint8Array, so I remove that line, insert the response data directly, and the blob size is now around 55K.      This editor is goofy.      async getImgSrc(dataCode) {
            const res = await ProfileService.getProfileImg({ token: this.dm.user.token, dataCode: dataCode });
            const blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: res.headers["content-type"] });
            const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            return urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
        }  But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Here is my binding:  <img :src="getImgSrc('1010001')" />   This is ridiculous because sites like FaceBook are able to do this.

Comment: Unless someone sees an error in my logic, I've come to the conclusion that this method isn't popular for a reason - perhaps unreliability at least. I've noticed others who have faced a similar issue. It turns out even Facebook doesn't truly hide supposedly private images (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sagu-71mc_I). I tried it, and it no longer works, but I suspect it's just a matter of time before it's again cracked. No less I'll have to design a solution which exposes the images publicly but only for a short period. Wow - unbelievable in 2020. Thanks, anyway, for trying to help me get t

Comment: I have since replaced the getImgSrc() with a variable and assign to the variable (using await) instead because getImgSrc is an async function. But it still doesn't work. Although I'm exploring a diff solution, I'm going to remain open to this solution since it's supposed to work. I don't want to have to expose files publicly.

Answer (score 1):

Final solution is to use image-to-base64 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-base64) on server and download the base64 string and plug it into the img src as src="data:image/(ext);base64,...". Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme As you know it makes the download 33% bigger, but that's the cost of privacy! Have fun!!